# Send Email by hangfire without using <mailSettings> in webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, hangfire

I worked with `asp.net mvc 5` `C#`.
I want to send email by hangfire without get data from `webconfing`.
In webconfig I have this code:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="email@site.com">
    <network host="host" port="25" userName="email@site.com" password="*****" enableSsl="false" defaultCredentials="false" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

when I use  in Webconfig ,everything works correctly.
But now I want to store email and password in database and get the value from database.

this is .cs code

```
 [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 20)]
        public static void SendEmailToMember(Member obj,string Subject, string Details){        
        var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));
                var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
                engines.Add(new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath));

                var emailService = new Postal.EmailService(engines);

                var ee = new SendEmailToMember
                {
                    To = obj.Email,
                    FullName = obj.FullName,
                    Subject=Subject,
                    Details = Details,
                    ViewName = "SendEmailToMember"
                };

                emailService.Send(ee);

}
```

How I can change it to get mail settings from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SmtClient` for create new `Postal.EmailService`, Import the  `System.Net.Mail` namespace and use this code

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"); //gmail smtp server
        smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("loginFromDB", "passwordFromDB");
        smtpServer.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpServer..EnableSsl = false;
        smtpServer.Port = 587; // gmail works on this port

        mail.From = new MailAddress("yourMail@gmail.com");
        mail.To.Add("recepient@gmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Hello from the other side";
        mail.Body = "your body";

        Postal.EmailService emailService = new Postal.EmailService(new ViewEngineCollection(), () => smtpServer);

        emailService.Send(email);
```

Comment: I want to send email using hangfire with postal.

Comment: @MarwaAlmahmoud Just create SmtpClient with own settings, next create new instante of postal email service using constructors, it is a sample but it works very well.